# Sliding Menu on Samsung phones are not showing app icon on action bar

Tags: android, menu, samsung-mobile, sliding

I changed all my previous tabs-activities app for a sliding_menu-fragments. The code to implement the sliding menu is using ActionBarDrawer (v4 which is deprecated now)

`mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        )`

The sliding menu is working fine. And the ic_drawer icon which is called the hamburguer (3 bars), appear well in my phone (One Plus One). Besides it, the app icon, appears also without problem. 
But running the same app on a Samsung phone the app icon disappear. Just the hamburguer is showed. 
Please if somebody was having a similar issue and have something to say I'll really appreciates any advice.

Comment: Hi, it was not related with Samsung but with Lollipop. Seems as the drawer menu on Lollipop is not showing the app icon in the action bar besides the hamburguer. Even I was checking this with the new V7 drawer framework (https://github.com/treehouse/android-navigation-drawer-final) and the app icon is not there. Any advice?

Comment: To whom can be interested, seems as Material design suppress the icon from the action bar. Even Gmail on material design is lacking the app icon.